# Running fails in Code-Blocks

Tags: windows-7, code-blocks

My system is Window 7. I'm using CodeBlocks. I run my hello world program again and again. The error messages as following always appear. Any idea for solving this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is not Code::Blocks. The problem is your C++ code is incorrect.**

`return0;` is not valid C++ code to the best of my knowledge. It should be `return 0;`. Most likely it was a build error (syntax error). Look down the bottom of the screen for `Build Messages`.
[[image: Screenshot w/ build error] 
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0rM4.png)

The default "Console project" in Code::Blocks should work, try that too.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry for the mistake. My code indeed is originally wrong. However, same message appears after I fix it and run the code.

Comment: Try pressing `F9`, Build & Run. If you just run without building, the message should appear if no build has been done since the code was last changed. Do you see any other messages in the log?

Comment: Did you download Code::Blocks with MingW? If you did not, you should have installed a compiler separately. To be sure it's not something wrong with your installation of Code::Blocks, try this: File > New > Project, Console application. Next > C++ > Next > Choose a title/location > GNU GCC Compiler (should be default) > make sure at least Debug configuration is checked. Once the project loads, press F9.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error message. The program must be built before it can be run.

Comment: The problem is that, I built it again and again, and this message still appears. How can I deal with it?